# grid CSS issue in td on some data

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]I had taken grid in which there are some `CSS issues` on grid td become distorted  Whats the reason for this?

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" class="grd" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itdrate" HeaderText="rate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itdAmou" HeaderText="amt" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itdquan" HeaderText="quantity" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itdrema" HeaderText="remark" />
       </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>


.grd
    {
        font-family:Verdana;
        min-height:400px;
    }
    .grd td
    {
       text-align:center;
       border: solid 1px #000000; 

    }
```

Comment: can you show screen shots?and css as well?

Comment: how can i show screen shot where shhould i post it

Comment: edit the question and add image,there is icon at the top list to add the image..

Comment: please show the CSS as well//

Comment: problem is when i added one more column i tested it the right side border distort

Answer (score 0):

In order to overcome this issue use the property **[NullDisplayText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext.aspx)** of BoundField and assign a blank space into that

**Example :**

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" NullDisplayText="&nbsp;" />
```

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

add a CSS class to the grid

```
.style1
  { 
    min-width:200px;
  }
```

try  position:relative; too !